# R merge two data from JSON

Tags: json, r, merge

I am rather new to R and I need to do the following:

I have two different data sources in JSON format which correspond to two time series, based on different time period (but overlapping). Each table has the format: period, value.

I would like to generate a table which will be a merge of the two, putting missing (na) values to B if the corresponding period is only defined in A and vice versa.

Example:

`DataA
period; valueA
1980, 1
1981, 3
1982, 4
1983, 5`

`DataB
period; valueB
1983, 5
1984, 8
1985, 4
1986, 0
1987, 2`

And I would like

`Data Final
period; valueA; ValueB
1980, 1, na
1981, 3, na
1982, 4, na
1983, 5, 5
1984, na, 8
1985, na, 4`

I am a bit confused between tables, data frames and list and I think this is why my code does not work:

```
data_final_A<-jsonlite::fromJSON("https://api.db.nomics.world/api/v1/json/series/imf-weo-ngap-npgdp-fra-6")
data_final_B<-jsonlite::fromJSON("https://api.db.nomics.world/api/v1/json/series/oecd-eo-fra-gap-a")

period<-data_final_A$data$values$period
value_A<-data_final_B$data$values$value

table_A<-t(rbind(period, value_A))
table_A<-as.data.frame(table_A, row.names = c("period", "value_A"))

period<-data_final_B$data$values$period
value_B<-data_final_B$data$values$value

table_B<-t(rbind(period, value_B))
table_B<-as.data.frame(table_B, row.names = c("period", "value_B"))

dplr <- merge(x= table_A, y= table_B)
```

My datasets are the following:

head(table_A) # table_A goes on until 2008

```
  period value_A
1   1980    -0.473
2   1981    -1.268
3   1982    -0.807
4   1983    -1.540
5   1984    -2.097
6   1985    -2.618
```

head(table_B) # table B stops in 2006

```
  period       value_B
1   1985 -1.9656045947
2   1986 -1.9205245105
3   1987 -1.6475054919
4   1988  0.3946512289
5   1989  2.2192438689
6   1990  2.5759810216
```

The resulting table is just a gigantic table that have the size of dim(table_A)*dim(table_B).

Thank you for your help, and by the way, I know my code is very messy and I am sorry about this, I am still exploring but I am really stuck.

All best,

T.

Comment: You are showing your code, which is a good start, but we don't have your json files, nor do we need the code that reads them. Alternatives that would be more useful here would be some minimization of each dataset either (a) dumped with `dput(head(...))` or the code to create it manually (e.g., `data.frame(a=1,b=2)`). I understand that you are confused, but we cannot help if you do not give us a little more information. (And by little, I suggest that reducing a problem-statement to datasets with only a few rows each is helpful to both you and us.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have changed my original message

Comment: That's a good start. Now realize that you want to do a join/merge on the two data.frames -- on `period`, I'm assuming -- but there is only one row in common between them. If this is intentional, then your join will be either 1 row or almost half `NA`. Your statement *"have the size of dim(table_A)*dim(table_B)"* doesn't really make sense; the code doesn't do or suggest that, and if it is what you want then a vanilla `merge` is not what you want/need.

Answer (score 0):

I've you tried to join them like

```
dplr <- merge(table_A, table_B, by=c("period"))
```

This should work.

Comment: I got this error "Error in sort.list(bx[m$xi]) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you call sort on a list?"

Comment: Tochoka, if that is the case, then there is something else with your data. This code functions without warning/error for me.

Comment: This code is functionally *identical* to the OP code. The default behavior is `merge(...,by=intersect(names(x), names(y)))`, so it adds nothing except an explicit argument.

Comment: When I run it, I have two errors/warning messages:

first: 
`table_A<-t(rbind(period, value_A))
Warning message:
In rbind(period, value_A) :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)`

Then the one `Error in sort.list(bx[m$xi]) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list' Have you call sort on a list?` when I run the last line

Comment: Is that possible to get the schema of the data sets your trying to join. There's probably something with the type of the col period.

Comment: I have added the links to the original JSON codes, other than that, table_A and table_B have dimensions 43, 2 and 35, 2.